# fibrations and hairbrush: an intuition

Tags: intuition, fibration

I would like to see why [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration) it cannot be globally the case $E=B\times F$ and $\pi$ for the porjection in the **hairbrush** case ? Also what corresponds to $h,p,\tilde{h}_0$ in hairbrush.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4638819/how-is-pi-1-leftu-i-right-different-from-u-i-times-f-in-fiber-bundles/4638864#4638864) help?

Comment: the page you linked to does not mention a hairbrush. What is "the **hairbrush** case"?